# Simple ember-cli-simple-auth and oauth2 project

Tags: authentication, ember.js, oauth-2.0, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm very new to 3rd party authentication and have not been able to make an API request to LinkedIn through the ember-cli-simple-auth addon paired with simple-auth-oauth2. My environment.js is below, where I've tried to piece together parts from Simple Labs' introduction1 and http://ember-simple-auth.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html1, specifically at the bottom of where environment === 'test'. I don't get any errors after building the CLI project but I do get a notification in the browser's console (not warning or error) that says:

```
No authorizer was configured for Ember Simple Auth - specify one if backend requests need to be authorized.
```

Right now, I'm just trying to get an auth token back from LinkedIn and am not sure what the next step is. If I try to trigger the "authenticate" action on my login controller (extending the loginControllerMixin), I get an error in the console saying:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: No authenticator for factory "authenticator:simple-auth-oauth2" could be found
```

What part or parts did I miss?

---

Environment.js:

```
// config/environment.js
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'seminars-me',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

APP: {
  // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
  // when it is created
}


 };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.baseURL = '/';
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

// keep test console output quieter
ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';

ENV['simple-auth-oauth2'] = {
  serverTokenEndpoint: 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=757ll7ci1xd93u&scope=profile'
};
    ENV['simple-auth'] = {
      authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer',
      crossOriginWhitelist: ['https://www.linkedin.com'],
      store: 'simple-auth-session-store:local-storage'
    };
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {

  }

  return ENV;
};
```

Comment: Did you install both `ember-cli-simple-auth` and `ember-cli-simple-auth-oauth2`?

Comment: @marcoow Yea I did and the terminal didn't output any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authenticator is actually registered as `simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant` while you're using `authenticator:simple-auth-oauth2`.

Comment: I found out that the LinkedIn API doesn't actually support cross-domain requests with CORS. What would you suggest be the best way to remain using a cli based ember app and still be able to make requests to the LinkedIn API?

Comment: Docs: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api & https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens